# Python logging module - time since last log

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I would like to add to the logs generated by Python's logging module the time (seconds/ms) passed since the last entry was made to the logs.

This is useful, so you can look at a log file to see whether the same step always takes the same amount of time or changing, indicating that something has changed in the environment (e.g. database performance).

I know about the %(relativeCreated)d, but that is only showing the time passed since the initiation of the logger and not since the last logs was made.
Basically the %(relativeCreated)d is the cumulated value, what I would like to see is the difference between each %(relativeCreated)d.

This is what you get with %(relativeCreated)d:

```
2015-07-20 12:31:07,037 (7ms) - INFO - Process started....
2015-07-20 12:31:07,116 (87ms) - INFO - Starting working on xyz
2015-07-20 12:31:07,886 (857ms) - INFO - Progress so far
```

And this is what I would need:

```
2015-07-20 12:31:07,037 (duration: 7ms) - INFO - Process started....
2015-07-20 12:31:07,116 (duration: 80ms) - INFO - Starting working on xyz
2015-07-20 12:31:07,886 (duration: 770ms) - INFO - Progress so far
```

Comment: Logging events should be independent of each other. It seems this is more suitable for a higher-level log analysis tool.

Comment: @SimeonVisser that makes sense to make it thread- and process-safe, but in case of a sequential ETL-like script it would be useful and not overly complicated to set a global variable with time everytime the logger is called so next time it is called it can just take the difference and display before setting it again. Obviously in multi-threaded or multi-process script it makes no sense to display such "time lapsed" information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be a done using a custom `logging.Filter` instance. Here is an example using the [`logaugment`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logaugment) library or you could look [at the source](https://github.com/svisser/logaugment/blob/master/logaugment/__init__.py) to build something similar.

```
import datetime
import logging

import logaugment

logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(time_since_last)s: %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

After creating a logger you'd specify a function that will be called every time a logging record is created:

```
def process_record(record):
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    try:
        delta = now - process_record.now
    except AttributeError:
        delta = 0
    process_record.now = now
    return {'time_since_last': delta}

logaugment.add(logger, process_record)
logger.warn("My message")
```

Example:

```
# 0:00:02.127129: My message
```

This will convert a `datetime.timedelta` object to a string. You can format that as a value in milliseconds using:

```
try:
    formatted = '{}ms'.format(delta.total_seconds() * 1000)
except AttributeError:
    formatted = '0ms'
return {'time_since_last': formatted}
```

which would require Python 2.7+ (for `total_seconds()`).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect! I did not know about logaugment... works very well.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the answer from @Simeon Visser -- the filter is a simple storage device to store the last message's relative time since script start (see `self.last` in `TimeFilter` class).

```
import datetime
import logging

class TimeFilter(logging.Filter):

    def filter(self, record):
        try:
          last = self.last
        except AttributeError:
          last = record.relativeCreated

        delta = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.relativeCreated/1000.0) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(last/1000.0)

        record.relative = '{0:.2f}'.format(delta.seconds + delta.microseconds/1000000.0)

        self.last = record.relativeCreated
        return True
```

Then apply that filter to each log handler and access the relative time in the log format string for each log handler.

```
fmt = logging.Formatter(fmt="%(asctime)s (%(relative)ss) %(message)s")
log = logging.getLogger()
[hndl.addFilter(TimeFilter()) for hndl in log.handlers]
[hndl.setFormatter(fmt) for hndl in log.handlers]
```

Comment: How can this code be modified to work with two handlers (console and file)? In my case, elapsed_time for the second handler is always zero.